Jetty crashed due to Segmentation faults
Jetty crashed due to Segmentation faults .
Logs:
May 26 07:33:49 filr jetty.sh[32201]: 2024-05-26 07:33:49.813:INFO::main: Redirecting stderr/stdout to /var/opt/jett>
May 26 07:33:49 filr jetty.sh[32201]: 2024-05-26 07:33:49.813:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML call setErr
May 26 07:34:39 filr systemd-coredump[32747]: [] Process 32201 (java) of user 469 dumped core.
May 26 07:34:39 filr systemd[1]: vabase-jetty.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
May 26 07:34:39 filr systemd[1]: vabase-jetty.service: Failed with result 'signal'.

core dump has been created but can someone guide how to analysis this core dump. I think I can use gdb.
gdb executable core-file 

what should I pass value in place of executable? My application written in java and jetty used as server.
There is no much info in application logs to analyzed this issue.


what should I pass value in place of executable?

The java binary which you are running. If that's the java on your PATH, then you can invoke gdb java /path/to/core.
Once there, use GDB where command to find out where the program crashed.
